# UITapGestureRecognizer's numberOfTouchesRequired behaviour on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, ios13

Using the following code, I intercept taps with 3 fingers:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector( // selector here))
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 3
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

The code works as expected on iOS 12. On iOS 13 though, the action is not called.

Removing this line:

```
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 3
```

Makes the action get called when the screen is tapped with one finger, but that's not the behaviour I am looking for.

What should I change in order to make the action get called when the screen is tapped with 3 fingers on iOS 13?

Comment: Probably the gesture recognizer is conflicting with the new cut/copy/paste and/or undo/redo system gestures. You can use the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`, `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`, and `shouldReceiveTouch` APIs to adjust the behavior.

Comment: This appears to be a known bug in iOS 13, and should be fixed in iOS 13.1
https://www.theverge.com/2019/9/20/20876211/apple-ios-13-fortnite-pubg-mobile-gesture-bug-unplayable-broken-games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 13.1 was released today, which fixes the issue with `numberOfTouchesRequired` set to 3.

Comment: Thanks, I confirm that the code from my question is working as expected on iOS 13.1